# How to install DevExtreme Application in Visual studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mobile, devextreme

How to install DevExtreme Application in Visual studio templates to get the installed template list as below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should download most recent installation from [DevExpress DevExtreme official site](https://www.devexpress.com/Products/HTML-JS/) and install it.
Note, that it willn't work with Visual Studio Express editions.

Answer (score 0):

It should work with just installing this file to Visual Studio http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/eb35fb7b-9071-41d1-9cfa-0fd5c6c46cb8